# Can someone help me understand this nested Mach-Zehnder interferometer by explicitly writing down the photon states in each steps?

Tags: quantum-optics, interferometry

[image]

The inner interferometer is balanced
and it is tuned to destructive interference toward the final
beam splitter of the external interferometer. The
external interferometer has beam splitters with transmissivity
1:2 and it is tuned such that the photon cannot reach detector
D when arm B is blocked. It can reach detector
D when nothing is blocked inside the interferometer

Comment: Can you provide some part of your calculation? What part of the question do you have trouble with?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1v-4hfis6llNFmlzMSKxuvmfRlMGMyIAy  I have tried this way.

Comment: Google drive links are subject to link rot and should not be used to include a document in your question. You should add the picture directly to your question. Also note that the site supports MathJax/LaTeX formatting, which should be used preferentially as handwritten notes can be more difficult to read. You will probably find help more easily with a proper formatting.